# dovecot - preventing outlook creating folder when language is changed

Tags: dovecot, outlook

I'm running a dovecot server and noticed when users changing the Windows/Office language to german Outlook creates an additional folder 'Entwürfe' - which is shown in the maildir folder as:

```
rwx------  5 vmail vmail 4096 Jan 16 01:55 '.Entw&APw-rfe'
```

I tried to prevent this from happening because there is already the Drafts folder which is used by Outlook - but it's still being created:

```
mailbox Drafts {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox "Entwürfe" {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox "Entw&APw-rfe" {
    special_use = \Drafts
    auto = no
  }
  mailbox Entw&APw-rfe {
    special_use = \Drafts
    auto = no
  }
```

How do i prevent the folder to be created?
The mappings for other german Outlook folders like 'Papierkorb', 'Gelöschte Elemente' are working and not created when switching the language by doing folder mappings like above.

Running dovecot 2.3.4.1 with maildir mailbox format and Outlook 2019

Thanks